# Custom Arduino with CH340 not showing up as USB device

Tags: arduino, pcb-design, usb

I just had some custom Arduinos manufactured, and it's the first time I've included a USB controller, CH340. I'm able to flash the bootloader to the Atmega2560 over ICSP, so the AVR is fine. However when I connect the USB cable, there is no device showing up at all. Its not a driver issue, there is no sound and I doublechecked in usbdeview. Also tried other cables, so I'm suspecting I messed something up in the design since its the first time I'm including USB.

The exact chip used is [this one](https://jlcpcb.com/partdetail/wch_jiangsu_Qin_heng-CH340C/C84681), datasheet. I followed [this example](https://cdn.hackaday.io/files/293271254726368/nano_ch340_schematics-rev1.pdf) when wiring it up, except I have no crystal as the CH340C is supposed to have a built-in crystal.

Anything obvious standing out please?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like the CH340 gets no power. Power is blocked by capacitor C14. This capacitor was probably meant for decoupling. But that's not how its connected. Try to shorten it for a first test.

Comment: I noticed i made a moronic mistake with the decoupling capacitor C14.. However even if i bypass it and verify 4.65V at the CH340, there is still no USB device showing up.

Comment: @Codo Yeah i just noticed, however it still doesnt work even if i remove it and short the gap.

Comment: I feel for you.  My experience is the USB coding without the good tools is very frustrating.  When you don't hear that "gadunk" it could be almost anything, from hardware, to the descriptor, to the code.  Do you have some sort of USB sniffer you can use to see how far along the USB protocol gets before it stops trying to enumerate?

Comment: The next problem with your circuit is the floating V3 pin. In your 5V setup, it is supposed to have a capacitor to ground.

Comment: @Codo Missed that completely. Thanks. Nothing to lose trying to short it to ground and seeing what will happen i guess?

Comment: Be careful with that one. I would actually try it with a capacitor. With the capacitor, it sets the voltage level but no current flows. Without the capacitor, a high current could accidentally flow.

Comment: If you have an oscilloscope, you can watch D+ and D-. Immediately after connection, D+ should go to 3V and D- should stay at 0V. If this is correct, the host will detect a full-speed device and start communicating and voltage levels should switch between about 0V and 3V.

Comment: @Codo That 3V3 capacitor was the last issue. Able to flash Blink via USB now. That will teach me to read datasheets properly and thoroghly. Pls post it as an answer and i will accept. Thank you for saving my sanity.